# chef file cache not where expected

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

While trying the following example on chef leaning:

https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/ubuntu/configure-the-database/

I ran in to an issue with this piece of code

```
# Create a path to the SQL file in the Chef cache.
create_tables_script_path = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'create-tables.sql')
```

The file is not showing up in the location specified:

```
STDOUT:
       STDERR: sh: /tmp/create-tables.sql: No such file or directory
       ---- End output of mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u db_admin -pdatabase_password -D my_company < /tmp/create-tables.sql ----
```

The file does show up in:

```
/tmp/kitchen/cache
```

Any ideas on what to tweak?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just editing the execute code block below that in the chef learning example to point the the (i guess new default) location:

```
# Seed the database with a table and test data.
execute 'initialize my_company database' do
  command "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u db_admin -p I_luv_flapjacks -D my_company < /tmp/kitchen/cache/create-tables.sql"
  not_if  "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u db_admin -p I_luv_flapjacks -D my_company -e 'describe customers;'"
end
```